# How do I rewrite this class so that it maintains the users in Arraylist instead of the array presented in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

This is part of an overall system of a mailbox so there shouldn't be any change in the interface methods of the class since I will then have to change the overall system.

```
public class Userlist
{

  private User[] users; 
  private int maxUser;  
  private int numberUsr; 

  public Userlist()
  {
    maxUser = 2;     
    users = new User[maxUser];
    numberUsr = 0; 
  }

  public User findUser(String username)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberUsr; i++)
    {
      if (users[i].userName.equals(username))
        return users[i];
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void addUser(User u)
  {
    if (findUser(u.userName) != null)
      System.out.println("User already exists");
    else
    {
      if (numberUsr == maxUser)
      {
        maxUser = 2 * maxUser; // double the size of the array
        User[] usersTmp = new User[maxUser]; 
        System.arraycopy(users, 0, usersTmp, 0, numberUsr); 
        users = usersTmp; 
      }
      users[numberUsr] = u;
      numberUsr++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of the ArrayList class? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Is your question, "How do I use ArrayLists?"

Comment: Why does every user instance have the array of users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Userlist
{

  private ArrayList<User> users; 

  public Userlist()
  {
    users = new ArrayList<User>();
  }

  public User findUser(String username)
  {
    for (User i : users)
    {
      if (i.userName.equals(username))
        return i;
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void addUser(User u)
  {
    if (findUser(u.userName) != null)
      System.out.println("User already exists");
    else
    {
     users.add(u); 
    }
  }
}
```

To learn about `ArrayList` look at [this](http://www.examiner.com/article/a-simple-java-arraylist-example), [this](http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/arraylist/) and of course [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Note: (More advanced options)
You can override the `equals()` method in the `User` class and omit the `findUser` method completely;

```
class User {
    String userName;
    /*
     * 
     * Do whatever 
     * 
     */

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        boolean theSame = false;

        if (object != null && object instanceof User)
        {
            theSame = this.userName.equals(((User) object).userName);
        }

        return theSame;
    }
}
```

instead check for existence of a user with

```
if (users.contains(u))
      System.out.println("User already exists");
```

Comment: you can use contains, instead of find user, right?. Of course, if the equals/hashCode implementation discriminate by username

Comment: @GarisMSuero> Yes, of course. I'll add this as comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `User[] users`, which is the array, use `ArrayList<type>`. Read about it more  here ---> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html and
here ---> http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/use-array-lists-in-java.html